# How can I have one keyword OR a different one in NewsAPI python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, pypi

I'm using Python 3.X, with [NewsAPI.org](https://newsapi.org)'s API. I want to be able to find news articles that have a keyword from a list of keywords. I tried putting commas in the keyword part of NewsAPI's url, but that just returns articles that have ALL of the mentioned keywords included.
Here is my code:

```
url = ('https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?'
       'q=Google, Apple, Microsoft&'
       'sortBy=popularity&'
       'apiKey=API_KEY')
parser = html.parser.HTMLParser()
response = requests.get(url)
```

Answer (score 1):

The part of OR in a HTTP request is not depending on Python or on any other language.

As per [newsapi's docs](https://newsapi.org/docs/endpoints/everything) Advanced search is supported:

> - Surround phrases with quotes (") for exact match.
> - Prepend words or phrases that must appear with a + symbol. Eg: +bitcoin
> - Prepend words that must not appear with a - symbol. Eg: -bitcoin
> - Alternatively you can use the AND / OR / NOT keywords, and optionally group these with parenthesis. Eg: crypto AND (ethereum OR
>     litecoin) NOT bitcoin.

I tried this and i think it works

```
import requests

url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/everything'

params = {'q': 'Google OR Apple OR Microsoft',
                'sortBy':'popularity',
                'apiKey': 'apiKey'
               }

response = requests.get(url,params=params)
```

Comment: In the above params, if I want the query 'q' to be 'Google OR Apple OR Microsoft Windows' instead of 'Google OR Apple OR Microsoft', can I do that, i.e. does this query support space separated words?

Comment: @vvvsss i think so.

Comment: @vvvsss ```https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=%22microsoft%20windows%20%22&apiKey=APIKEY``` this worked for me with only micorsoft windows